# How do i open these apps?

Tags: unity, 16.04

Today i installed 7zip, furious ISO mount and mate power manager. FuriousISO is in my dash, whereas the other two are not.

All 3 show up in software center and in terminal ~$dpkg -l as installed. Im unable to open/use 7zip at all, and when trying to run power manager from terminal, it simply brightens the screen. (No GUI? Not compatible with Unity desktop?)

Was kinda aiming to personalize my power settings for when my machine is plugged/unplugged.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**7zip**

`7zip` is only a tool for command line. Functionality for using 7zip as a compression is *added* to the "archive manager" desktop tool.

Top right shows '7z' as a compression option when `7zip` is installed ...

[image]

**Mate power manager**

As you can read in any of the [manual pages](https://www.mankier.com/1/mate-power-manager):

> `mate-power-manager` is the backend program of the MATE power management infrastructure providing a complete and integrated solution to power management under the MATE desktop environment.

and it also points to [mate-power-preferences](https://www.mankier.com/1/mate-power-preferences).

> mate-power-preferences is the gui program for the mate power management infrastructure

So you also need that one.

Comment: Ah i see the 7zip now, thanks :-) As for mate-power-preferences, did i request it right: jester@JR2:~$ sudo apt-get install mate-power-preferences
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mate-power-preferences

Comment: I missed this: "Not compatible with Unity desktop?" Yes. that tool is for the "mate" desktop, not Unity. You probably do not see the options in "power management" due to that. https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/mate-power-manager-common also talks about package `mate-power-manager-common` but without the "mate" desktop repo's you probably wont have that (?)

Answer (score 0):

For 7zip GUI install Archive Manager, Ark or File Roller. These are actually independent archivers, but they make use of 7zip. FuriosISO is kinda useless to me. Archivers can decompress ISO files in linux, and you can mount ISO files in linux just like you do in Windows 8 by right-clicking on file and choose Mount.